# Google Analytic's events sent not showing up in dashboard

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using the Google Analytics snippet below

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'icantreveal.com');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

I am sending my events on say a button click as follows

```
//google analytics click event hit record
if(typeof(ga) == "function")
  ga('send', 'event','int_lp_btn','int_lp_findPeople_btn');
```

I am using Google Analytics debug Chrome addon for testing purpose. However when I test the same in my site I can see in console

> Executing Google Analytics commands. Running command: ga("send", "event", "int_lp_btn", "int_lp_findPeople_btn") Sent beacon:some ga stuff

However the event report in dashborad does not have anything to show!. I have been unable to figure out what the problem is. Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: are you checking the Real-time reports in Google Analytics or the standard report?

Comment: standard report which takes some time to get the analytic data!

Comment: Exactly it takes 24 to 48 hours for data to appear how long did you wait? Check real-time is it registering it there?

Comment: No not exactly 24 hours i guess. how do i check the real time whether event reg or not.

Comment: thanks man its capturing but i think it will take some time to appear in standard report i guess! cool :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your google tracking ID and set page view as  `ga('send', 'pageview');`